# How to have a button which is projected outside the NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

I want to implement a button which is projected outside the NSView. The similar button is shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Place the button outside the view.

Comment: @swapnil, did you mean outside the **window**? It's hard to tell from your image. The gradient (shadow?) makes me think that's the edge of a window.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to draw outside of an NSView. Even if it were, you wouldn't get any mouse events outside the view's frame (unless you tinkered with `hitTest:`). It *is* possible to change an NSView so it doesn't clip its subviews, allowing a child view to sit outside its frame. I suspect the button you're describing is a separate view, possibly in a transparent child window (that's they way I'd do it).

Comment: You may be able to create another window and add as `childWindow` of main window. Think in that direction.

Comment: As you can see in the image, half button is inside the view and half  button in outside the view. If I directly put some portion of the button outside the view, outside portion of button is not visible.

Comment: Which part of the image is the view? Which part of the image is the window? Why can't you make the view bigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to have a view overflowing the window, you can't do that using the `masksToBound` property of `CALayer`. You need to use a child borderless window and position it correctly.

Here's an example (in ObjC):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application


    NSRect windowFrame = self.window.frame;
    NSRect childWindowFrame = {
        .origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(windowFrame) - 25,
        .origin.y = CGRectGetMinY(windowFrame) - 25,
        .size.width = 50,
        .size.height = 50,
    };

    NSWindow *childWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:childWindowFrame
                                                        styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless
                                                          backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                            defer:YES];
    childWindow.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
    childWindow.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
    childWindow.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
    childWindow.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;



    [self.window addChildWindow:childWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
}
```

The red circle in this screenshot is the child window.

[image: overflowing child window]

Answer (score 1):

in swift it will be like

```
 func addChildWindow(){
    guard let window = self.view.window else {
        return
    }
    let windowFrame = window.frame
    var childWindowFrame = NSRect()
    childWindowFrame.origin.x = windowFrame.midX - 25
    childWindowFrame.origin.y = windowFrame.minY - 25
    childWindowFrame.size.width = 50
    childWindowFrame.size.height = 50
    
    let childWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: childWindowFrame,
                                styleMask:.borderless,
                                backing: .buffered,
                                defer: true)
    
    childWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
    childWindow.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
    childWindow.contentView?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    childWindow.contentView?.layer?.cornerRadius = 25.0
    window.addChildWindow(childWindow, ordered: .above)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making sure your parent view is layer backed and setting the masksToBounds property of its layer to false.

Here's an AppKit playground showing this in action:

```
//: A Cocoa based Playground to present user interface

import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let nibFile = NSNib.Name("MyView")
var topLevelObjects : NSArray?

Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibFile, owner:nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)
let views = (topLevelObjects as! Array<Any>).filter { $0 is NSView }

let rootView = views.first as! NSView

// create parent
let parentView = NSView()
rootView.addSubview(parentView)
parentView.wantsLayer = true
parentView.layer?.masksToBounds = false
parentView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
parentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
parentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
parentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

let childView = NSView()
parentView.addSubview(childView)
childView.wantsLayer = true
childView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
childView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
childView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
childView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true


// Present the view in Playground
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = views[0] as! NSView
```

This will draw:

[image]

The green view is a child of the red view.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please provide this in objective c?

Comment: I think the views which you have shown in your screenshot is inside the NSWindow. I want to show half button outside the NSWindow.

Comment: That’s different. To make that happen you need to place the button in another borderless window and add that as a child of the main window. You can’t have views drawn outside their window.

Comment: But how can I set the frame to the child window? So it looks similar to the window shown in my screenshot.